# 403 error when deploying Node.js website to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

I was following [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/) to deploy a simple `node.js` web app to Azure.
Deplyment went fine - but when I visit the website - I get 403 `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

my node.js code:

```
var http = require('http')
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('Hello from azure\n');
}).listen(port);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might because of your directory structure. Maybe your `server.js` file was located in a sub folder of your git repository. Could you check the deployment log from azure portal (just click the down-arrow icon besides your recent deployment). It should tell you azure detected this is a node app. And in your case it might be not.

Alternatively you can login the azure website scm portal, just navigate to the url `https://[your-site].scm.azurewebsites.net/`, and your can see the folder/files deployed and check the structure.

HTH