# Error after deploying node js app to MS azure service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, socket.io, web-deployment

So i create an app using node, socket IO, and when i start deploying it everything goes smooth but i started to get 500, 503 and 504 errors but then i made some changes and redeployed it but then i got rid of these errors i was getting but instead i am getting 403 forbidden error saying that i do not have the permission, this is a social network app i am deploying using VS code and Azure but i cannot figure it out because this is the first time of me using azure services

Here is my main code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port =  process.env.PORT || 3000;
const middleware = require('./middleware')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const mongoose = require("./database");
const session = require("express-session");
const http = require('http');
// const server = require('./server');



const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server listening on port " + port));
const io = require("socket.io")(server, { pingTimeout: 60000 });

app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", "views");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(session({
    secret: "bbq chips",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))

// Routes
const loginRoute = require('./routes/loginRoutes');
const registerRoute = require('./routes/registerRoutes');
const logoutRoute = require('./routes/logout');
const postRoute = require('./routes/postRoutes');
const profileRoute = require('./routes/profileRoutes');
const uploadRoute = require('./routes/uploadRoutes');
const searchRoute = require('./routes/searchRoutes');
const messagesRoute = require('./routes/messagesRoutes');
const notificationsRoute = require('./routes/notificationRoutes');

// Api routes
const postsApiRoute = require('./routes/api/posts');
const usersApiRoute = require('./routes/api/users');
const chatsApiRoute = require('./routes/api/chats');
const messagesApiRoute = require('./routes/api/messages');
const notificationsApiRoute = require('./routes/api/notifications');

app.use("/login", loginRoute);
app.use("/register", registerRoute);
app.use("/logout", logoutRoute);
app.use("/posts", middleware.requireLogin, postRoute);
app.use("/profile", middleware.requireLogin, profileRoute);
app.use("/uploads", uploadRoute);
app.use("/search", middleware.requireLogin, searchRoute);
app.use("/messages", middleware.requireLogin, messagesRoute);
app.use("/notifications", middleware.requireLogin, notificationsRoute);

app.use("/api/posts", postsApiRoute);
app.use("/api/users", usersApiRoute);
app.use("/api/chats", chatsApiRoute);
app.use("/api/messages", messagesApiRoute);
app.use("/api/notifications", notificationsApiRoute);

app.get("/", middleware.requireLogin, (req, res, next) => {

    var payload = {
        pageTitle: "Home",
        userLoggedIn: req.session.user,
        userLoggedInJs: JSON.stringify(req.session.user),
    }

    res.status(200).render("home", payload);
})

io.on("connection", socket => {

    socket.on("setup", userData => {
        socket.join(userData._id);
        socket.emit("connected");
    })

    socket.on("join room", room => socket.join(room));
    socket.on("typing", room => socket.in(room).emit("typing"));
    socket.on("stop typing", room => socket.in(room).emit("stop typing"));
    socket.on("notification received", room => socket.in(room).emit("notification received"));

    socket.on("new message", newMessage => {
        var chat = newMessage.chat;

        if(!chat.users) return console.log("Chat.users not defined");

        chat.users.forEach(user => {
            
            if(user._id == newMessage.sender._id) return;
            socket.in(user._id).emit("message received", newMessage);
        })
    });

})
```

[image]

Screenshot of the error.

Comment: Dayan ibrar, Any update to the issue

Answer (score 0):

All the native modules are not supported in Azure App Service so might fail at compiling those with specific very prerequisites.

There are 2 workarounds proved successful with almost all native modules available today:

- Run npm install on a Windows system that has every prerequisite for the native module set up. After that, upload the application to Azure App Service along with the newly formed node modules folder.
- You have the option to perform custom commands and precisely control how npm install is being run by configuring Azure App Service to execute custom bash or shell scripts during deployment.

Refer to the [Custom Website Deployment Scripts with Kudu](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/custom-web-site-deployment-scripts-with-kudu/) provided by Microsoft.

If the error is 403 when deploying nodejs to MS Azure service, then Thank you [Shaun Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120704/shaun-xu) posting your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227651/403-error-when-deploying-node-js-website-to-azure) as an answer here to help community member .

Also Refer this [403 forbidden error](https://github.com/lostintangent/node-azure/issues/26) for more insights!

If you're getting 500 errors without proper messages, then i would like to suggest you some troubleshooting steps:

**How to check real errors instead of 500**

1. In azure portal for your app service enable diagnostic logs
2. Select log stream
3. Refresh your site. Now you should see real error message in log stream.
4. Make sure that your entry point is in the root folder.

   - If your entry point was './bin/www', manually move this file to root and update the and sections in the Web.config to get it working.
   - Deploy again after making these changes.

---

You can choose to enable [diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json) for web apps in Azure App Service. Depending on the level you select, information will be logged, and you can review the log files on Azure Storage or Azure System.

For easy online troubleshooting, you can use the Console and Streaming Logs. IISNode module manages Node.js applications on Azure Web Apps. For further information, see Best practises and troubleshooting guide for node apps on Azure Web Apps. You may then use the IISNode configuration to enable the module's log capability.

As stated in Debug your app with [Node-Inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode#debug-your-app-with-node-inspector), Node-Inspector may be used with node.js applications.

---